# Scope Angularjs $resource parameters to HTTP Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angularjs-resource

By default, Angular's $resource.$save method sends a request with parameters in the "base" scope. For example, creating resource with properties `{name: 'John Smith', email: 'john.smith@gmail.com'}` will result in a POST with parameters:

```
name=John Smith&email=john.smith@gmail.com.
```

However, I have a Rails controller that **needs** the resource scoped to a sub-hash (more like the normal railsy way of doing things). I would want that same create request to have parameters:

```
user[name]=John Smith&user[email]=john.smith@gmail.com
```

The problem is, I just don't see a way to do this using $resource. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished by using `$resource`'s `transformRequest` option. Below is an example using the `update` action (written in coffeescript):

```
update:
  method: 'PUT'
  transformRequest: (data, headersGetter) ->
    data = _.omit(data, '$promise', '$resolved')
    json = {'user': data}
    return JSON.stringify(json)
```

If you want to do this by default, I recommend writing a service that wraps `$resource` and adds the `transformRequest` functions to all actions.